# Add Class to Following Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, gallery

I had a look out on the interwebs for a jQuery image gallery and couldn't find one that suited what I wanted to do. So I, ended up creating one myself and am trying to figure out how to get the prev and next buttons to work.

```
<div class="gallery portrait">
    <nav>
      <div class="close"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="prev"><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div class="next"><a href="#"></a></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm also using a bit of jQuery to add a class of `.full` to the `.thumb a` element, which makes the thumbnails go fullscreen.

```
$( ".thumb a" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "full" );
  $( "nav" ).addClass( "show" );
});
```

Now I can't work out this next bit, I need a way when the `.prev` or `.next` buttons are clicked for it to remove the class of `.full` from the current element and add it to the next or previous `.thumb a` element, depending on which was clicked.

I've got a demo setup here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/hjvBG

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

P.S. If this turns out well, I plan on releasing it for free. I guess you can't have too many jQuery image galleries, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $.next() and $.prev():

```
$(".prev").click(function () {
    var current = $('.full');
    current.prev('.thumb').addClass('full');
    current.removeClass('full');
    return false; // stop propagation; prevents image click event
});

$(".next").click(function () {
    var current = $('.full');
    current.next('.thumb').addClass('full');
    current.removeClass('full');
    return false; // stop propagation; prevents image click event
});
```

Comment: This is great, and seems like it should work, but for some reason it wont. I edited some of the JS, and updated the demo here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/hjvBG

Comment: I took a look at your updated demo. You are referencing the `a` in all of your code. $.next() and $.prev() will only return siblings. You'll need to get to a point where you are working with siblings, get `li` you need, and then go to the a. I will update the code real quick.

Comment: @realph Your demo code is all over the place in terms of where you are adding the class, or how you are accessing them. $('.full a').removeClass('full'); won't do anything, because it is against the `a` tag, not the actual tag with the full class...

Comment: So, what are you saying?? Remove all the anchor tags from the thumbnails?

Comment: Try using `$('a.full')` instead of `$('.full a')`

Comment: I've updated the demo and that seems to work a treat!! Have a look: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/hjvBG Is there a way I can get it to cycle through instead of ending at thumbnail 3?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47140/discussion-between-bic-and-realph)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following additions to your code to handle wrapping around with your next and previous links:

```
$(".next").click(function (event) {
  navigate("next");
  return false;
});

$(".prev").click(function (event) {
  navigate("prev");
  return false;
});

function navigate(operation) {
  var $thumbs = $(".thumb"),
      $full = $thumbs.find("a.full").closest(".thumb"),
      $next;
  $thumbs.find('a').removeClass('full');
  if (operation == 'prev' && $full.is($thumbs.first()))
     $next = $thumbs.last();
  else if (operation == 'next' && $full.is($thumbs.last()))
    $next = $thumbs.first();
  else
    $next = $full[operation]();
  $next.find('a').click();
}
```

Here is a [forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/koBqr).

Comment: That works great, but is there a reason why it cycles fine through the thumbnails previously, but stops after the third image when you cycle through by pressing next? Also, when cycling previously, the 2nd thumbnail no longer appears.

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue in Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome here too. Mac v.32.0.1700.107.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you started, but what you're wanting to do takes a little time to get just right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var imgSrcs = ['/imgs/this.jpg', '/imgs/will.jpg', '/imgs/work.jpg', '/imgs/just.jpg', '/imgs/fine.jpg'];//img url loaded into an array


    var btnPrev = document.getElementById('prev'),
        btnNext = document.getElementById('next'),
        cover = document.getElementById('cover'),
        thumb = document.getElementById('thumb'),
        currImgIx = 0;

    btnPrev.onclick = function () {

        if (currImgIx === 0) { return; };

        currImgIx--;
        cover.src = imgSrcs[currImg];
        thumb.src = imgSrcs[currImgIx];
    };

    btnNext.onclick = function () {

        if (currImgIx === imgSrcs.length - 1) { return; };

        currImgIx++;
        cover.src = imgSrcs[currImgIx];
        thumb.src = imgSrcs[currImgIx];
    };

</script>

<div class="gallery portrait">
    <nav>
        <div class="close">X</div>
        <div id="prev" class="prev">Prev</div>
        <div id="next" class="next">Next</div>
    </nav>
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="#"><img id="cover" src="image.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img id="thumb" src="image.jpg"></a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```